# How can I initialize a global nested Dictionary globally?

Tags: c#, dictionary, static, initialization, global-variables

I have my Dictionary declared like this:

```
private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> myDictionary;
```

I want to initialize it globally.  The closest I have come initializes the outer Dictionary, but still leaves me with a null reference to the inner Dictionary:

```
private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> myDictionary
 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

I need to avoid initializing it in a method, because I don't want to force the user to call a method before being able to use my class.  The user only has access to static methods.  I could create a singleton when they call one of the methods, but that's dirty.

How can I declare both dictionaries globally?  Something along the lines of one of these (although neither compile):

```
private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> myDictionary
 = new Dictionary<string, new Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

or

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> inner = new Dictionary<string, string>();
private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> myDictionary
 = new Dictionary<string, inner>();
```

Comment: Note that you don't have one "inner" dictionary: you will need as many "inner dictionary" as the number of items you add to the (single) "outer" dictionary

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Might be helpful in coming up with the answer you are looking for

Comment: @konkked I am writing a wrapper for a C# project to be used in Unity.  Any more details would be a conversation too long for the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [static constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx) like this (assuming that the `myDictionary` variable is in a class called `MyClass`) :

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> myDictionary;

    static MyClass()
    {
        //Initialize static members here
        myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
        myDictionary.Add("mykey", new Dictionary<string, string>());
        ...
    }
}
```

The framework will make sure that the static constructor is automatically executed before you access any member of the class.

Answer (score 4):

You can initialize it inline without doing it in a method by following the [`{}` collection initialization syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4034719/335858):

```
private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> {
    {   "first"
    ,   new Dictionary<string, string> {
            {"A", "one"}
        ,   {"B", "two"}
        }
    }
,   {   "second"
    ,   new Dictionary<string, string> {
            {"Y", "twenty five"}
        ,   {"Z", "twenty six"}
        }
    }
}
```